# In Pandas dataframe column how to convert string column into list

Tags: pandas, string, list

I read data from mssql and as in data format below:

```
 from pandas import DataFrame
 import pandas as pd

  data = pd.DataFrame({'Index':[1,2],'Metrics':[" 
  ['ga:users','ga:newUsers']","['ga:bounceRate','ga:pageviews']"]})
```

What I need is list of each row dimension column:

```
 list1= ['ga:users','ga:newUsers']
 list2=['ga:bounceRate','ga:pageviews']
```

below what I tried but :

```
  Metrics1=data.loc[data['Index']==1,'Metrics'].iloc[0][1:-1].split(', ')
```

I got some extra  "

```
  ["'ga:users','ga:newUsers'"]
```

How can I fix this please help? Thank you

Comment: You have the `"`s in your original definition of `data`. Are you looking for an automated way of removing them? If you can trust the source, you can use `eval()`, but that is not safe in general.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is the safer way